# Optimizing Neural Network speed for larger inputs (Facial Recognition)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am building a neural network to recognise the difference between male and female. The issue is that I have a database with a collection of 250x250 pixels (Not x 3 since I convert to grey-scale). Meaning the input layer consist of 62500 neurons. I use 1 hidden layer with 5 neurons. There are 5000+ images. This is allot of computations that needs to be done. Simply too much.

So my what I want to know is if there are better/quicker techniques and ways to use when working with such a large input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two simple tricks that might be useful:
1. reduce the resolution (for many tasks we can reduce the resolutions considerably without losing too much information, maybe try something like 30*30 as a starting point
2. batch size do not need to be very large (maybe around 20 will do for this task?

If available, using GPU could be a lot faster.
For deeper networks, there're tricks like [pooling and stride](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) that can reduce the size of input for subsequent layers.

Please feel free to correct me where I'm wrong. :)